# variable substitution in bash from different source files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have small snippet of code in `bash`

```
# below variable coming from a source file
test_name_tgt_tbl='abc_123'

# this variable coming from another source --> source 2
red_test='test_name'

# Based on source2 variable I need to find value in source 1
out_put=`echo ${red_test}_tgt_tbl`

echo "target=`echo $out_put`"
```

The result I am getting is below

```
target=test_name_tgt_tbl
```

The result I want is below

```
target=abc_123
```

How can I achieve that

Comment: foo=\`echo $bar\` is a really bad way of writing `foo=$bar`, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that indirection in bash by writing `${!some_var_name}`. Here's how I would go about it:

```
var_name=${red_test}_tgt_tbl
echo ${!var_name}
```

Prints `abc_123`.